# Create click event to programmatically created div

Tags: javascript, for-loop, onclick

I am trying to create divs that appear at real time (using jQuery and XML).
After you click that div I want that the user will get redirected to a URL depending on the div he clicked.
the divs are created in for loop and it works fine.
My problem is that each div gets the last value of `i` which is 5.

```
for(i=0; i<5;i++){
    var div= document.createElement("div");
    div.id="conv"+i;
    div.innerHTML=conv[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("conv").appendChild(div);

    $("#conv"+i).click(function(){

        alert(this.id);
        var form= document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method","post")
        form.setAttribute("action","watch_conv.php");
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "chat_room");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value",chat_room[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        form.appendChild(hiddenField)
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        //form.submit();
        alert(i);
    });
    $("#conv"+i).animate({opacity:"show"});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that your callback will run after the original loop completes.  So at the point that your `alert()` runs, `i` will be 5.  If you want to use the original value of `i` with which the div was created inside your callback, you'll need to obtain it some other way, such as parsing it out of the id or retrieving it from a custom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

That's standard behaviour for javascript. In order to make the value of i stick around in each iteration of the loop, you'll need to use a closure :

```
$('something').click((function(i) {
    return function(e)
    {
        // now you will have access to variable "i" the way you'd normally expect
        alert('clicked on ' + i);
    }
})(i));
```

Comment: Ok I think this is what I am looking for. But what is it a closure?

Comment: A closure, or an inner function remembers the variables of its parent function at the time of execution. Basically in the example above you create an anonymous inner function and immediately execute it, thus capturing all the values of its parent vars (in this case we only need i though). So now it does not matter that the loop has already completed, you'll have the "i" of each iteration in the child function. Try googling closures for more detailed explanations as it might take some time and a few more articles to understand them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the 'i' variable is changed because you are using a for loop, which increases it. So instead of getting i, retrieve the number by using

```
alert(this.id.replace('conv', ''))
```